# How to remover ghost space after the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

This content is actually loading from a 3rd party script (CodeFund Ad), I redesign almost everything in CSS by this ghost space after the image still here...

[Secreenshot is here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClJXu.jpg)
below is the CSS code that in use:

```css
#codefund {
    display: grid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    min-height: 85px;
}

#codefund #cf {
    max-width: 330px;
    color: var(--text-color) !important;
}

#codefund #cf img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    clear: both;
    padding:0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

#codefund #cf a {
    display: block;
    outline: 0 none;
    border: none;
    color: var(--text-color-lighter);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px !important;
}

#codefund #cf span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--text-color-gray);
}
```

```html
<div id="codefund"><!-- fallback content --></div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML content?

Comment: <div id="codefund"><!-- fallback content --></div>  This is only HTML that is in use... Content loaded in it... souce code shows the same code without any change

Comment: I mean can you show an example of what the fallback content HTML looks like. So that it can be reproduced in a codepen. In your CSS your selecting elements inside the `#codefund` div.